# Make a query to the same table with values in different Rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have to display in the same line results that are in 2 rows in a table in SQL example:

```
**Name     Lastname  address        U_Name**
John     Smith     123 N Av       NULL
E-mail   NULL      js@123.com     John

Result
**Name    Last name   e-mail**
John    Smith       js@123.com
```

Thanks

My current query looks like this

```
select C2.UREPEMAIL, 'NULL' as Source, CS.TITLE, CS.CONTACT, C1.COMPANY, C2.UGMNAME as Vendor, CS1.Contsupref, 'NULL', 
CS.PHONE, CS.EXT, CS.FAX, 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL' Skype, 'NULL', CS.TITLE, 'NULL', 'Department', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'Pref of Con',
'NULL', CS.ADDRESS1 + ' ' + CS. ADDRESS2, CS.CITY, CS. STATE, CS.ZIP, CS.COUNTRY, CS.ADDRESS3, 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL',
 'NULL'  
from CONTSUPP CS         
INNER JOIN CONTSUPP CS1
ON CS.CONTACT = CS1.ADDRESS2
INNER JOIN CONTACT1 C1
ON C1.ACCOUNTNO = CS.ACCOUNTNO
INNER JOIN CONTACT2 C2
ON C2.ACCOUNTNO = CS.ACCOUNTNO
```

Comment: Does your table have any keys?

Comment: please be specific about question. Improve your question with table columns and sample data and output properly

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Theres a key that links to other table but the only way to link the 2 rows are with Name and U_Name

Comment: @krishnar It took some time but now has format to better understand with table columns and sample data

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
SELECT  a.Name,
        a.Lastname,
        b.Address
FROM    YourTable a
        JOIN YourTable b
            ON a.Name = b.U_Name
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this and works but since I have more date and when I aplly a filter with a where it does not respect it since its the same table

Comment: please post your query to the the original question with the date and the WHERE clause you are referring to

Comment: Thanks @SEarle1986 I just changed the Join to LEft Join and that add also the ones that did not have e-mail

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data size is very limited so I added some data that will display a failure (*when name <> u_name*) because you need to locate some reliable method of joining the first part of the record to the second part of the record. If that relationship doesn't exist you can identify this (due to the null u_name).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5fe93/2)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (  `Name`    varchar(20)
     , `Lastname` varchar(20)
     , `address` varchar(100)
     , `U_Name`  varchar(20)
    )
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`Name`, `Lastname`, `address`, `U_Name`)
VALUES
    ('John', 'Smith', '123 N Av', NULL)
  , ('E-mail', NULL, 'js@123.com', 'John')
  , ('Barney', 'Rubble', '123 N Av', NULL)
  , ('E-mail', NULL, 'br@123.com', 'brubble')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select 
  t1.Name, t2.U_Name, t1.Lastname, t1.address, t2.address as email
from table1 t1
left join table1 t2 on t1.name = t2.u_name and t2.name = 'E-mail'
where t1.name <> 'E-mail'
order by t1.name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5fe93/2/0)**:

```
|   Name | U_Name | Lastname |  address |      email |
|--------|--------|----------|----------|------------|
| Barney | (null) |   Rubble | 123 N Av |     (null) |
|   John |   John |    Smith | 123 N Av | js@123.com |
```

Comment: Thanks @Used_By_Already the left join was the thing missing thanks!